# Getting coincident information between rows

Tags: r, rows, probability, estimation

I would like to estimate the percentage of samples  (`(0:1)` limits), descripted as `Sam` columns, which have exactly the same information in the above and below probes (designed as `Abo`and `Bel` in `dfout`, respectively) AND which samples are the coincident ones between above and below probes (designed as `SamsA`and `SamsB` in `dfout`, respectively).

The input `df`:

```
     df <-  "Sam1  Sam2 Sam3 Sam4 Sam5 
Prb1  0       0    1    2    3    
Prb2  0       0    1    2    2    
Prb3  0       1    1    2    2    
Prb4  2       2    3    2    2" 

df <- read.table(text=df, header=T)
```

The expected output `dfout`:

```
dfout <-  "Abo Bel SamsA SamsB
        Prb1   NA  0.8  NA   Sam1-Sam2-Sam3-Sam4
        Prb2  0.8 0.8  Sam1-Sam3-Sam3-Sam4 Sam1-Sam3-Sam4-Sam5
        Prb3  0.8 0.4  Sam1-Sam3-Sam4-Sam5 Sam4-Sam5
        Prb4  0.4 NA Sam4-Sam5 NA"

    dfout <- read.table(text=dfout, header=T)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the approach I would take, using a `for()` loop and if statements for clarity (these could be collapsed and vectorized if efficiency is of utmost importance:

```
df <-  "Sam1  Sam2 Sam3 Sam4 Sam5 
Prb1  0       0    1    2    3    
Prb2  0       0    1    2    2    
Prb3  0       1    1    2    2    
Prb4  2       2    3    2    2" 

df <- read.table(text=df, header=T)


for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  if (i > 1) {
    Sams <- df[i-1,1:5] == df[i,1:5]
    df[i,"Abo"] <- sum(Sams)/5
    df[i,"SamsA"] <- paste(names(df)[1:5][Sams], collapse="-")
  }
  if (i < nrow(df)) {
    Sams <- df[i+1,1:5] == df[i,1:5]
    df[i,"Bel"] <- sum(Sams)/5
    df[i,"SamsB"] <- paste(names(df)[1:5][Sams], collapse="-")
  }
}

out <- df[,c(8,6,9,7)]
```

The `out` object looks like this:

```
> out
     Abo Bel               SamsA               SamsB
Prb1  NA 0.8                <NA> Sam1-Sam2-Sam3-Sam4
Prb2 0.8 0.8 Sam1-Sam2-Sam3-Sam4 Sam1-Sam3-Sam4-Sam5
Prb3 0.8 0.4 Sam1-Sam3-Sam4-Sam5           Sam4-Sam5
Prb4 0.4  NA           Sam4-Sam5                <NA>
```